# PHP associative array to binary file

Tags: php, arrays, performance, binaryfiles

I have a lot of array data, and it takes a lot of space to store in plain php script. It might take a while to read the script and store it in memory. So I wanna try save the data in binary format, but I have no any idea how that works

How can I save multi dimension associative array like

```
$var = array(
  array('name'=> 'name1', 'age' => 23),
  array('name'=> 'name2', 'age' => 23),
  ...
);
```

to a binary file? and read it again in another script?

Comment: If your file needs to read the array then pack it... or unpack the binary then read it... how does the extra step save memory?

Comment: well, im not sure too. Im trying to find a solution to speed up dealing with large arrays

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336528/memory-optimization-in-php-array

Comment: i kinda interested with method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702192/php-and-the-million-array-baby  but i dont know the multidimension array equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php), [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function to do it.